# MSFT Graph API: Unable to filter GUEST users on my tenant

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using the following endpoint to query only GUEST users in my tenant

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenantId>/groups/<groupId>/members?api-version=1.5&$filter=userType%20eq%20'Guest'
```

This is returning the following error

***Status code*** `400`

***Response body*** `{"error":{"code":"Request_UnsupportedQuery","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported."}}}`

How can I get past this error?

Comment: It seems that AAD Graph API doesn't support this filter query of `userType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like Azure AD Graph API doesn't support this filter query of `userType` currently.

According to my test, Not all properties are supported. So, I suggest you can post this give a feedback about Azure AD Graph API in [this Uservoice Page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?category_id=165567). Azure Team will review it.

Hope this helps!